# On Spinner how can i access the value mentioned in string.xml

Tags: android, arrays, xml

how do i access the **value** from string.xml

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item value="in">India</item>
</string-array>
```

i want if some one selects **India** then i can get **in**

```
countrySelector.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

This gives **India**

Comment: Create a dictionary for that.

Comment: @TusharPandey that will take a lot time. It's very long.
i have data in the above manner

Comment: sorry, then create another array like <item value="India">in</item> and find the match.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, here is an example:

```
String[] countries= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
String country= countrySelector.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Or you can respond on user selection:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    String country = countries[pos];
}
```

Comment: India is the value you have in your xml data, you can filp in and india and it will work

Comment: nope. @meda you are not getting me,
i want to show `india` in spinner where as i want to receive `In` only